# How to enable user shell theme extension in latest Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, gnome-tweak-tool

In the latest version of Ubuntu, which is Ubuntu 17.10 with default desktop environment of GNOME, Ubuntu has disabled user theme extension in gnome tweak tool. Because of that I can't change the theme of GNOME. How do I enable / install the user theme extension?

Comment: Maybe related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-shell-extensions/+bug/772221

Comment: Could you expand a bit more? What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I goto install dash to panel extension.  How to install it

Comment: Have you tried removing and reinstalling from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/)?

Answer (score 3):

I did a fresh install of 17.10, and the User Themes shell extension wasn't installed by default.

You can install the extension by downloading it from [here on the GNOME Shell Extensions site](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/).

After installing the **User Themes** extension from the website, enable it via the Tweak Tool (if not already enabled) and close/reopen the Tweak Tool. Then the option to change the shell theme should be available on the first page.

On my system, I couldn't install shell extensions from the website because the GNOME Shell Integration connector wasn't installed. You can install that by running this at a terminal:

```
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
```

If you have to install the connector, refresh the extension page in your browser before you attempt to install the extension.

Comment: this should be the accept answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question.

Essentially, I typed in Tweak on the search, and it took me to the Ubuntu Software Centre to re-install it.

Voila.